# How to structure SQL resources table where rates change periodically but history must be maintained?

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

For a database still in design, asking for best way to design resources table.  I want to calculate the labor cost of projects.  I receive timesheet data and I maintain a resources table.  If employees never got raises, I would determine the cost as:

```
SELECT t.proj_id,
       t.person,
       t.hours,
       t.hours * r.rate AS cost
FROM timesheet t
     INNER JOIN resources r ON t.person = r.person;
```

This gets complicated if Bob Smith gets a raise on June 1.  Now I need to maintain the cost of Bob's old work at the old rate and his newer work at the new rate.  What is the best way to design the resources table to make this work?

I believe the right way to do this is by adding start and end fields to the resource table and adding a second record for Bob. But what is the best way to make sure my query captures the correct rate for Bob?

Comment: Sorry, should have said- using Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain a history table. For example your table 
t_b_employee_rate_hist ( employee_id int,rate decimal(10,2),start_date date,end_Date date) last active record will have end_date null.
Then you read table with current rates.

```
merge into t_b_employee_rate_hist  h
using(select employee_id,rate from current_rate_table) c 
h.employee_id=c.employee_id and end_date is null and h.rate<>c.rate
when matched then update set h.end_date=current_date - 1 day
```

This will close active record then you have to insert new ones

```
 insert into t_B_t_b_employee_rate_hist
 select  employee_id,rate,current date,cast(null as date)
 from current_rate_table 
 where employee_id in 
  (select employee_id from t_B_t_b_employee_rate_hist
     where end_date current_date - 1 day);
```

You can create this as job at that will run daily, date functions will vary according to  database.